# Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) delivers results that are unrelated to the training data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, gaussian

[image: from left: entry and exit points, GMM with 2 components, GMM with 3 components]

As you see in the image, the clustering seems not related at all to the provided data.
I have 34 data points.
What could be the reason of this?

fitting K GMM with different components:

```
  def calculate_zones(self):

    mini_data = []
    for id, enter_x, enter_y, enter_time, exit_x, exit_y, exit_time in self.data:
        mini_data.append([enter_x, enter_y])
        mini_data.append([exit_x, exit_y])

    K = range(2, 4)

    for k in K:
        # Set the model and its parameters
        self.gms.append(
            GaussianMixture(n_components=k, n_init=20, covariance_type='spherical', init_params='kmeans').fit(
                mini_data))
```

masking the image based on the results of the GMM:

```
  def display_zones(self):
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_path)
    if not video.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open stream")
        exit()
    _, frame = video.read()

    mask = []

    colors = random_color(11)

    for model in self.gms:
        curr_mask = np.zeros_like(frame)
        mask.append(curr_mask)
        row_index = 0
        for pixel_row in frame:
            column_index = 0
            for _ in pixel_row:
                prediction = model.predict_proba([[row_index, column_index]])

                best_proba = 0
                counter = 0
                for one_prediction in prediction[0]:
                    if one_prediction > prediction[0][best_proba]:
                        best_proba = counter
                    counter += 1

                curr_mask[row_index][column_index] = colors[best_proba]
                column_index += 1

            row_index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should fit one GMM per class. GMMs are an unsupervised probabilistic algorithm so you cannot provide multiple classes to the `.fit()` function and expect it to differentiate between classes innately (unless your purpose is to map the areas together, then this approach is fine).

Secondly, you train your model using data formatted as:

```
mini_data = []
for id, enter_x, enter_y, enter_time, exit_x, exit_y, exit_time in self.data:
    mini_data.append([enter_x, enter_y])
    mini_data.append([exit_x, exit_y])
```

But then obtain predictions using:

```
for _ in pixel_row:
     prediction = model.predict_proba([[row_index, column_index]])
```

Shouldn't the inputs to your function be `[[column_index, row_index]]` to match the `[x,y]` format of your train data?

Comment: your second point is correct, I switched between row_index and colum_index. But regarding the first point, as far as I understand, GMM with BIC and EM, together they can estimate the number of classes and cluster them, I plot the means and covariance and the results look pretty good. why do you believe that each class should have a single GMM? the point of unsupervised is that you don't know how many classes you have...

Comment: Yes exactly. So, if you want to do clustering and find which cluster a datapoint belongs to (unsupervised), then that is fine, as hopefully each cluster should mostly consist of one class. However, if you want to characterise your classes you need to separate your GMMs across your classes. When you do a predict_proba() on the new data from each GMM then your largest likelihood will represent the correct GMM class.

Comment: Ok I get it, in case where a class has multiple clusters, then I should give each class a GMM, but in my case I don't have classes in that sense, I'm just looking for clusters. Can you maybe edit your answer and explain that a class can have multiple clusters. Because it confuses me at first.

Comment: then I can accept your answer :)

Comment: It all really depends on your data. If you cluster height and weight as a function of gender, then you’d expect there to be a correlation between women being shorter/lighter and men the opposite. However there will be clusters that contain more than 1 class because this is obviously not a super discrete class separation. So therefore, the clusters can not be distinctly labeled as one class because there isn’t that distinct separation of the data.